# Hibernate Criteria object - perform a INTERSECT

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I was wondering if their is an easy to perform a oracle INTERSECT using the Criteria API object.

Using Hibernate 3.2

**EX. I want all of the t.value that exist in 'table' where the names are dora and diego.**

**SELECT t.value from table t where t.name = 'Dora'**

**INTERSECT**

**SELECT t.value from table t where t.name = 'Diego'**

I am thinking I will have to use Restriction sqlRestriction or write a oracle stored procedure that is called that does it. Any other suggestions?

### Solution 1:

```
    Session sessionFactory = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();         
    String intersetSQLQuery = "SEE QUERY STRING BELOW";     
    SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.createSQLQuery( intersetSQLQuery );
    query.addScalar( hibernate_mapped_field_name,Hibernate.STRING);
    //Returns a list of string objects
    nameList = query.list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Intersect isn't currently supported.  See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1050

You may be able to get away with something like

```
select t.value from table t 
where t.name = 'Diego' 
and t.value in 
    (select t1 from table t1 
     where t1.name = 'Dora')
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work and its also has better performance in a oracle database than an INTERSECT. This query is almost twice as good as a INTERSECT. Really surprised no way to do it in Hibernate. 

Had a typo in it though I corrected. Line 3 where you have 'and t in' should be 'and t.value in'

Comment: Interesting edit.  Are you considering this SQL or HQL?  I was going with HQL, in which case I would leave it with `and t in` where the sub-select is selecting instances of type table.  Otherwise, you would want the sub-select to be selecting t1.value and not t1 so that it matches your t.value (which I'm assuming is unique?)  In any case, you know your schema better than I do so I approved your edit.

Comment: Yes I did use native sql. I posted the solution above. Didn't try with HQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why  not just:

```
select  t.value from table t where t.name in ('Diego', 'Dora' )
```

- just like that.

Never try to omit the power of sql.